# Printing Web Page but partial words are pruned

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, printing, print-to-pdf

I am using Windows 7.

When I try to print the following page
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter1_Introduction/Chapter1_Introduction.ipynb

the print out keep pruning text as shows in the following (by blue circle, e.g., for "homepage", it only give "homep"):

[image]

How to make those pruned words appear? (I am not restricted to chrome, any methods could work on Windows 7 are ok for me)

Comment: Either print it landscape or change the margins.

Comment: @cybernard tried, there is no use

Comment: Forget the margins, click properties on the PDF printer and change the paper size to A0.

Comment: @cybernard Thanks, but ultimately I need to print out to printer using A4 paper, is there a way to make it appear fully on A4 paper? (also the text appear strangely in pdf if I print using A0)

Comment: In addition to below you could try a less extreme page size like A3 and then **Shrink to fit** that on a A4.

Answer (score 0):

Goto **File** and **Page Setup**.

Either **Shrink to fit Page Width** or reduce the **Scale**

[image: PageSetup]

Comment: Which browser do you get the page setup window?

Comment: This is from FireFox

Comment: IE also has this option, but in Chrome it appears to be buried deep within the menus.